# Formatted output for git log inconsistent with non formatted output

Tags: git, git-log

I've just cloned the Keras repository and was interested in looking at the git log. I initially tried using a pretty format, and got this for the last 4 commits:

```
me@ARL--M6800:~/Downloads/keras$ git log --pretty=format:"%cn %cd %h"

François Chollet Tue Jan 17 13:29:21 2017 -0800 55487f3
François Chollet Mon Jan 16 17:14:16 2017 -0800 1c6db08
François Chollet Mon Jan 16 10:05:35 2017 -0800 e54d795
François Chollet Sat Jan 14 21:33:04 2017 -0800 82ca6d4
```

However, when I didn't format the output, I got these results for the last 4 commits:

```
commit 55487f33b135849cdda49bcc75778976d94a2575
Author: Javier Dehesa <javidcf@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 17 21:29:21 2017 +0000
 ...
commit 1c6db0815853f7c5421b8057e9167f19b5b94812
Author: Petr Baudis <pasky@ucw.cz>
Date:   Tue Jan 17 02:14:16 2017 +0100
...
commit e54d7951f2a82629c71c77ca842ba032b523fe84
Author: Pat York <pat.york@nevada.unr.edu>
Date:   Mon Jan 16 10:05:35 2017 -0800
  ...
commit 82ca6d418588ccd61d663ec8029937290b62d583
Author: Mohanson <mohanson@outlook.com>
Date:   Sun Jan 15 13:33:04 2017 +0800
```

Although the hashes match, the author and commit dates do not. Does anyone know why this is and what it means?

Comment: Can you run `git log --format=fuller` and check whether `Commit` and `CommitDate` fields match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %ad %h"
```

as %cn gives you the commiter name and %an the author name (displayed in "normal" log)

From the manpage:

```
       ·   %an: author name

       ·   %aN: author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))

       ·   %ae: author email

       ·   %aE: author email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))

       ·   %ad: author date (format respects --date= option)
```

vs.

```
       ·   %cn: committer name

       ·   %cN: committer name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))

       ·   %ce: committer email

       ·   %cE: committer email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))

       ·   %cd: committer date (format respects --date= option)

       ·   %cD: committer date, RFC2822 style
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `%cd` displays the committer date in one timezone (`-0800`) whereas the default format prints the dates in their local timezone. That makes at least some sense and the timezone differences match.

About the author I have no clue...

Comment: That's it. To get the author, I just switched to %an for the name and &an for the date. I'm feeling a little silly, since a better (or more varied) read of docs should've gotten me there